# Define a relationship between two SQL Server tables (parent to child column) without the use of unique or key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, relationship

I am trying to build a table which will hold the 'relationship' of a parent table and a child table. However each column in both tables are no keys or unique and there are duplicate values in each.

Example

Table A - Parent (Fact)

```
**CartNumber**
```

Table B - Child

```
**CartNumber** not unique
CartValue
```

`CartNumber` from table A links to `CartNumber` in B.

I have tried to implement a foreign key with NOCHECK but of course that will not work since the child column is not a primary key or unique. Bear in mind, I am ONLY trying to define that there is a link between the two columns/tables. Is there any way to define a 'loose' relationship between the two columns? Preferably a method where I can reference the sys views or information schema to extract this information

Comment: Not the most beautiful solution, but it might work to use a third table holding all unique used cardnumbers, then making both having a relationship to that table.

Comment: @SamuelKirschner the third table would be huge since its not just CartNumbers but a whole range of other columns, each used to link to another table. I guess the end goal is to almost have a table holding the path definition from one table to another

Comment: Do I get this correctly? There is a table with let's say persons. There is no unique key, so you look at their first name. There is a Bob, a Tom and a Tim, and one more Bob and one more Tim. Then there is some related data. The data knows, that it is somehow related to Bob, but does not need to know **which** Bob? This smells... Might help to explain some more background: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If what you are referencing is not unique, you won't be able to retrieve data specifically.(i.e. You might not get what you want with those references).

Comment: @xblade I just read your question once again and got the feeling, that you have a wrong concept of *relationship*. One Question: Is the **CartNumber** in `Table A` unique?

Comment: @Shnugo I have no knowledge about the data within the columns, but all I do know is that both the parent and child column is not unique. All I am looking to do is say "To get result Y you need to join column X from Table A onto Column Z in Table B" and that join is the path from the parent to the child

Comment: @Shnugo not a unique column in either table

Comment: @xblade why do you want to define such a relationship, for what purpose? is it merely to serve as a "comment" for other devs?

Comment: @Stephen its not a relationship by the usual definition. I do not want a physical link between the tables but something that can just be referred to that will tell a user or query that Column A from Table A is used to join onto Column B from Table B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest: This design smells and - if possible - you should think about changing this...

There is no chance to define a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` on non-unique columns the way you describe it.

But: **To define a `JOIN` there is no need for a FK!**

My suggestion:

Create a `VIEW` like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
SELECT a.Col1,a.Col2,...
      ,b.Col1,b.Col2,...
FROM TableA AS a
[INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER] JOIN TableB AS b ON a.RelField=b.RelField;
```

With such a VIEW you will get the data joined on this non-unique information.

### UPDATE

Taken form your comment:

> the end goal is just to provide an external web service with information that says Column A from Table A is used to join onto Column B from Table B

You can create a meta-table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ColumnReference
(
 ColumnReferenceID INT IDENTITY
,TABLE_NAME_A VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,COLUMN_NAME_A VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,TABLE_NAME_B VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,COLUMN_NAME_B VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
--inlcude SCHEMA if needed...
```

In this case you can maintain these relations in your own structure..., you might even add details, rules, what ever...

The web service will call this directly. You might use a VIEW to combine existing relations (defined as `FK CONSTRAINT`) with your own meta table (simply with `UNION ALL`).

Comment: Thanks @Schnugo, apologies if i worded it incorrectly but the end goal is not to extract data or worry about the data at all. Instead, the end goal is just to provide an external web service with information that says Column A from Table A is used to join onto Column B from Table B

Comment: Thanks Schnugo, something like this was actually my last resort as I assume the filling in of this table would be manual? There will be hundreds, nearing to the thousands, of columns so of course a lot of room for human error and maintenance. However if there is no other way then I guess this is the only approach

Comment: @xblade, what you describe is more **business rule** than **relationship**, at least in terms of database people... I doubt, that a user would be able to create a query out of this later... Well, define all **real relations** as `FK CONSTRAINT` and *relations by rule* as a meta-table. I would be really astonished, if this concept turns out as a wise and working design...